# Android saving and retrieving an object from a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, save

I've created an object that I need to save so the user can access the information in it later. I was using other questions, and tutorials to put it into a JSONobject, and then turn that into a string. After that, I would insert it into a table...

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("run", run);
String runString = json.toString();
SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("your runs",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Runs(Run BLOB);");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Runs VALUES('"+runString+"');");
```

To retrieve it I use this code...

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("Select * from Runs",null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
runArray = new Run[cursor.getCount()];
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    try {
            object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(cursor.getBlob(0)));
            run = (Run) object.opt("run");
            runArray[count] = run;
            count ++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This seems to work, but when I try to get a Run from the runArray, and get the name of the run it causes a null pointer exception. The runArray has a length of one, which should be correct because I only created one Run. Is this the proper way to retrieve the Runs, or should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: I would not do it that way at all.  If you're just going to save the data as a big blob of json, I wouldn't even bother with a database, just use 'SharedPreferences'.  If you want to use a database, use a real structure with fields that describe the data.

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm trying to just create a table with all of the necessary values. I'm stuck on trying to insert a String[], and a float[] into the table.

Comment: If you're trying to insert arrays, there's a good chance your database could be designed better.  Perhaps that should be another table with a foreign key to the table you're currently using, and each item in the array(s) is a row in that new table.

Comment: I got it. I ended up just converting the arrays into strings and putting them into blobs on a table. Then when I retrieved them, I converted them back to arrays. It works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of trying to put the Run object into the table. I just put all of the values from Run into the table. In the other activity that retrieved the values, I took the values and created a new Run with them.
Here's the code that inserts the values...

```
SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("your runs",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Runs(name VARCHAR, units VARCHAR, runtime VARCHAR, date VARCHAR, pace FLOAT, avgSpeed FLOAT, distance FLOAT, laps BLOB, speeds BLOB, distances BLOB);");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Runs VALUES('"+run.getName()+"','"+run.getUnits()+"','"+run.getRunTime()+"','"+run.getDate()+"','"+run.getPace()+"','"+run.getAvgSpeed()+"','"+run.getDistance()+"','"+Arrays.toString(run.getLaps())+"','"+Arrays.toString(run.getSpeeds())+"','"+Arrays.toString(run.getDistances())+"');");
```

And here's the code that retrieves it...

```
database = openOrCreateDatabase("your runs",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    cursor = database.rawQuery("Select * from Runs",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    runArray = new Run[cursor.getCount()];
    count = 0;
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        run = new Run();
        run.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        run.setUnits(cursor.getString(1));
        run.setRunTime(cursor.getString(2));
        run.setDate(cursor.getString(3));
        run.setPace(cursor.getFloat(4));
        run.setAvgSpeed(cursor.getFloat(5));
        run.setDistance(cursor.getFloat(6));
        run.setLaps(toArray(new String(cursor.getBlob(7))));
        run.setSpeeds(toFloatArray(new String(cursor.getBlob(8))));
        run.setDistances(toFloatArray(new String(cursor.getBlob(9))));
        runArray[count] = run;
        count++;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it works for now. I can improve it later.